# how to install kivy for python 3.10.2

Tags: python, module, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm getting problem in installing kivy for python 3.10.2
I tried to install kivy through vs-code and pycharm but I'm getting some errors
[image of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJQ2B.png)

please someone explain me why this is happening and solution for it

Comment: The [kivy.org websie](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html) says Kivy 2.0.0 officially supports Python versions 3.6 - 3.9

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.10.2 is unsupported for Kivy right now, so install Python 3.9([Download Python 3.9.4](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-394/)) and then type the command `pip install Kivy==2.0.0`. I'm using Python 3.9.4 with Kivy and it works fine